# PHP Database take average and counter

Tags: php, database, average

I have a database that has this

```
Date       -   Temp

2013-12-01 -   12    
2013-12-31 -   18
```

Holds 1 month. Im graphing this by JSON in my PHP page. But I want something different, to graph it weekly. Like It will take each 7 days temp average and if I find a suitable sql statement for it, it would be great.

I found this in my pdf.

```
SELECT Date,Temp COUNT(Date) AS weekly, AVG(Temp) AS Temperature 
    FROM temp2 GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date;
```

**But it will take all the 31 days which is not weekly but monthly.**

Anyways, is there something you can do?

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT YEARWEEK(date)` and `GROUP BY YEARWEEK(Date)`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by month and year in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366895/group-by-month-and-year-in-mysql)

Comment: I want average of temps 7 days by 7 days, so in the end I will have a table like 4 rows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997814/mysql-average-every-4-rows  OK Found the answer here!

Comment: So in what way does YEARWEEK() fail?

Comment: I have what I wanted right now but I also want to have another column named as Week and values are the row counts which is 4 or 5 atmost. I used something but it give 7 7 7 7 3 which is day count. How can I count the generated rows and print them like 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: OK Done that aswell. Thanks for replies btw.